# Is there a way to pass meta refresh in pandas to_html?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a dashboard that I am using aiohttp and pandas `to_html()` function to create a HTML table from an api scraping dataframe, basically. I'm using a simple memory cache and running it on a remote server, so I'd like to figure out how to have the page "auto refresh." I've been looking at a lot of websites but most of them have access to the backend HTML5 in order to configure `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />`. Because I am using `pandas.to_html`, is there a simple way to go about this within my python script, or will I need a js script to enable such a function?

Comment: you can not force the client to refresh on the backed side. Include the meta tag or write js.